# How to find the XPATH for the site "MarineTraffic" search (selenium for python) - Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector"

Tags: selenium, xpath

Although I am newbie on Python, I have searched for several hours before addressing this question.

Would you let me know how to properly find the XPATH from website [www.marinetraffic.com](http://www.marinetraffic.com) search?

I think the search box might be in a iframe, but I was unable to make it work (even after deeply checking/learning with the "SelectorsHub" extension.

My latest code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

Path = "C:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"
S = Service(Path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = S)

#Abrindo Marine Traffic
driver.get("http://www.marinetraffic.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//input[@id='searchMT'])[1]").send_keys("vessel", Keys.ENTER)#
```

error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\MarineTraffic.py", line 33, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//input[@id='searchMT'])").send_keys("vessel", Keys.ENTER)
  File "...\webdriver.py", line 1238, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "...\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "...\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to 
locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//input[@id='searchMT'])"}
```

I know this code works because other sites are responding fine (such as google, etc), but Marinetraffic.

I have tried

```
(By.ID, '//*[@id="searchMT"]')
(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#searchMT")
```

and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used execute script to type vessel in the search input box.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.marinetraffic.com/")

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='AGREE']"))).click()
except:
    print("AGree button did not show up")

search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchMarineTraffic")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'Vessel')", search)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Awsome, this worked fine, thank you so much @Cruisepandey...    Bonus question... How did you find the ID "searchMarineTraffic" ? When I am searching I can see only something like: id="searchMT"...

Comment: Strange I could not find `searchMT`, all I see is this `<input aria-invalid="false" id="searchMarineTraffic" placeholder="Search MarineTraffic" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart" value="">`

Comment: and I see <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="searchMT" placeholder="Search MarineTraffic" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd" value="">, well... thank you anyway!